# Is there a reason css for sticky headers works on other tables but not on gtsummary tables?

Tags: css, r, gtsummary

I have tried everything I can find online to modify this or that to make sticky table headers for my gtsummary table, to no avail. Using custom css to make sticky headers works just fine when I make tables using other packages, like arsenal. Is there a reason it doesn't work with gtsummary?

I created a simple gtsummary table in Rmarkdown, and wrote some css in a separate file which I called in the YAML header. I know the css is working in general because the very table header I'm trying to make stick has a box shadow just the way I've specified, but no stickiness.

This is my css code:

```
thead {
  background: white; 
  position: sticky;        
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Again, the box-shadow works fine, so I know it's identifying the right element. I've also gotten the box-shadow part to work by calling the th element instead of thead. But no matter what I do the header won't stick.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I am not an expert in CSS, but I did write gtsummary. Have you checked whether this occurs with plain gt tables? If the issue lies there, I think you'll have more luck with the gt tag (or posting an issue on their github page). If the stickiness works in gt but not gtsummary, I can troubleshoot with you.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering so quickly! I LOVE gtsummary, just got snagged on this one thing is all. I'll try gt and give an update on how it went here as soon as possible.

Comment: If it's going to be an issue for you using gt to print the tables, you can convert any gtsummary table to flextable, huxtable, kableExtra... https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html

Comment: Success! Following your suggestion by adding %>% as_kable_extra() solved the entire problem. You were also right about this being a problem with gt. This is incredibly fascinating. I wonder if the table header wasn't sticking simply because there are classes added to the gt table elements. But that doesn't explain it, because I can apply other css to the table header, just not stickiness. In fact, I can even make it a fixed header, but as soon as I change only one word in the css by swapping out 'fixed' with 'sticky', it doesn't work. But anyway, thank you so much for the solution!!

Comment: I have no idea how to accept the answer you've given. Stackoverflow says not to say thank you, and instead to click the gray check mark below the voting arrows. But there are no check marks to click, and I don't know of any other way to let you know you've solved it. Oh well I guess!

Comment: Since these are comments and not answers, they can't be accepted. I will propose one more gt solution. Try the `gt::opt_css()` function. The code will look something like this: `tbl_summary(trial) %>% as_gt() %>% gt::opt_css()` Perhaps that is the best way to inject CSS code into a gt table? "opt_css function | R Documentation" https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gt/versions/0.2.2/topics/opt_css

Comment: I tried the opt_css() function, but not exactly the way you've just described, with the part of adding the as_gt() as well, so I'll try adding that and let you know. However, since as_kable_extra() also worked, that could be considered a solution too, no?

Comment: I've tried opt_css again, but to no avail. I'll ask a question to the gt creators to see what they can add.